# How to make "Ckeditor-5 document editor" disabled or readOnly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor5

I'm using CKeditor5 document editor in reactjs. And i want to make it disabled or readonly. I'm sending parameter in config but not working.

```
<CKEditor2
                      editor={DecoupledEditor}
                      data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
                      onInit={editor => {
                        editor.ui.view.editable.element.parentElement.insertBefore(
                          editor.ui.view.toolbar.element,
                          editor.ui.view.editable.element
                        );
                      }}
                      config={
                        {
                          toolbar: ['bold', 'italic', 'bulletedList', '|', 'numberedList', 'alignment'],
                          removePlugins: ['Heading', 'Link'],
                          isReadOnly: true,
                        }
                      }
                    />
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?
EDIT: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_editor_editor-Editor.html#member-isReadOnly this is for ckeditor5

Comment: I don't know if it matters in ckeditor5 but in the 4 it has to be '=' instead of ':' otherwise it was not accepted.

Comment: @H.Figueiredo I'm looking for same but I don't know how to add the property

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I think I found out what you're looking for:

[Here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/react.html) you have a description of the component properties. On the last one you can see "disabled"

So you're code would look something like this:

```
<CKEditor2
                      editor={DecoupledEditor}
                      data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
                      disabled=true
                      onInit={editor => {
                        editor.ui.view.editable.element.parentElement.insertBefore(
                          editor.ui.view.toolbar.element,
                          editor.ui.view.editable.element
                        );
                      }}
                      config={
                        {
                          toolbar: ['bold', 'italic', 'bulletedList', '|', 'numberedList', 'alignment'],
                          removePlugins: ['Heading', 'Link'],
                          isReadOnly: true,
                        }
                      }
 />
```

Also, I think you probably meant `<CKEditor` instead of `<CKEditor2`.

Answer (score 2):

Use **editor.enableReadOnlyMode("editor");** [Docs](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_editor_editor-Editor.html#member-isReadOnly)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/35.0.1/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="editor">Test</div>
    <script>
      ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector("#editor"), {
        toolbar: [],
      }).then(editor => {
        editor.enableReadOnlyMode("editor");
        console.log(editor);
      }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```